# how to use hover content

Tags: html, css

I have a div, which when I hover over it, another div appears, which contains a button and a link that I want to be able to use.
But until I take the mouse off the first div to go to the displayed content, they disappear. what should I do?

```css
#account {
  display: relative;
}

#account_container {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 8.7%;
  right: 62%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 33.5%;
}

#account:hover+#account_container {
  display: block;
}

#account_container li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 117%;
  margin-right: -1%;
}

#li {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 15% 5% 5% 5%;
}

#li img {
  margin-left: 6%;
  margin-bottom: -3%;
}
```

```html
<div id="account"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" id="user" class="icon" /></div>

<div id="account_container">
  <ul>
    <a href="">
      <div id="li">
        <li>سلام</li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" /></div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div id="li">
        <li>سفارش ها</li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" /></div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div id="li">
        <li>علاقه مندی ها</li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" /></div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div id="li">
        <li>خروج</li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" /></div>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/content-on-hover-or-focus.html makes some relevant reading.

Comment: Your list markup is completely invalid. You can't just drop list items wherever you like. They must be children of a list, and the list can _only_ contain list items as children.

Comment: Also, IDs must be unique or they don't identify anything.

Comment: The problem you've presented is the same one that millions of dropdown menu creators have faced. I suggest that you look at how CSS dropdown menus are built.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add hover on your #account_container also,
Your div were 100% of width, removed it, or reduce the width to make it fit with your image.

Snippet below

```css
#account_container {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 8.7%;
  right: 62%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 33.5%;
}

#image_account:hover+#account_container, #account_container:hover {
  display: block;
}

#account_container li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 117%;
  margin-right: -1%;
}

#li {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 15% 5% 5% 5%;
}

#li img {
  margin-left: 6%;
  margin-bottom: -3%;
}
```

```html
<img id="image_account" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" id="user" class="icon" />

<div id="account_container">
  <ul>
    <a href="">
      <div id="li">
        <li>سلام</li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" /></div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div id="li">
        <li>سفارش ها</li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" /></div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div id="li">
        <li>علاقه مندی ها</li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" /></div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div id="li">
        <li>خروج</li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" /></div>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also add the hover event to the second div:

```
#account_container:hover {
  display: block;
}
```